# C++ and preprocessor macros: variadic type

Tags: c++, macros, variadic, preprocessor-directive

Take for example the following macro:

```
#define _CREATE_VAR(X1) double X1{smc::define_variable (data, X1, #X1)};
#define _CREATE_VAR2(X1,X2) double X1{smc::define_variable (data, X1, #X1)}; /
                        double X2{smc::define_variable (data, X2, #X2)}; /
#define _CREATE_VAR3(X1,X2,X3) double X1{smc::define_variable (data, X1, #X1)}; /
                        double X2{smc::define_variable (data, X2, #X2)}; /
                        double X3{smc::define_variable (data, X3, #X3)}; /
#define _CREATE_VAR4(X1,X2,X3,X4) double X1{smc::define_variable (data, X1, #X1)}; /
                        double X2{smc::define_variable (data, X2, #X2)}; /
                        double X3{smc::define_variable (data, X3, #X3)}; /
                        double X4{smc::define_variable (data, X4, #X4)}; /
#define _CREATE_VAR5(X1,X2,X3,X4,X5) double X1{smc::define_variable (data, X1, #X1)}; /
                        double X2{smc::define_variable (data, X2, #X2)}; /
                        double X3{smc::define_variable (data, X3, #X3)}; /
                        double X4{smc::define_variable (data, X4, #X4)}; /
                        double X5{smc::define_variable (data, X5, #X5)}; /
```

Is there a way to simplify this by using one macro `_CREATE_VAR` instead of having multiple instances with different variable argumentsand corresponding names? Ideally, I would like to automatically call the same macro `_CREATE_VAR` regardless of how many arguments.

Comment: What is the `data` variable and where is it coming from?

Comment: `data` is coming of a struct data-type and the object name happens to be called `data` atm. `data` is just where information of a variable is stored. This information is stored separately since I will need many instances and parts of `data` need not be copied. The main thing is `Xi's` becomes an object I can use in another class I can do numerical computations on. I need objects since each of my classes that use these variables are changing differently and other users will be using this interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind a slightly different call syntax, you can use [boost.preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) for that:

```
#include "boost/preprocessor.hpp"

// or to not include entire preprocessor header, the following header files will do
// #include <boost/preprocessor/stringize.hpp>
// #include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each.hpp>

#define CREATE_ONE_VAR(maR_, maData_, maVarName) \
  double maVarName {smc::define_variable (data, maVarName, BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(maVarName))};

#define CREATE_VAR(maSeq) \
  BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(CREATE_ONE_VAR, %%, maSeq)
```

Example of use:

```
CREATE_VAR((x1)(x2)(x3))  //does the same as your original _CREATE_VAR3(x1, x2, x3)
```

Now you can call it with any number of variables from 1 to `BOOST_PP_LIMIT_SEQ`, which is normally 256.

A few notes:
I use `%%` to indicate that the argument is unused. You can put anything in there (it gets passed to the internal macro's `maData` parameter, which we don't use).

You should not name your macros to start with an underscore followed by a capital letter. It's illegal according to the standard, as such symbols (as well as any symbol including two consecutive underscores) are reserved for your compiler.

Comment: @woosah Thanks for the edit; it was rejected before I had a chance to review it, so I've manually re-added your changes.

Comment: No worries, I didn't know macros can't have a single pre underscore. I always though it was double underscore. Ah well, you learn something new everyday !

Comment: It's a bit late now, but it's possible to keep the original calling syntax very easily by using `BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ`. It might be C++11-only, though. I'm not sure if Boost has any tricks up its sleeve around that.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to use a `FOR_EACH` macro on `__VA_ARGS__`, its not pretty and it probably takes a while to fully follow along with whats happening but at least it doesn't depend on `boost`.

Helper macros:

```
// Concatenates tokens, even when the tokens are macros themselves.
#define PP_JOIN_HELPER_HELPER(_0, _1)       _0##_1
#define PP_JOIN_HELPER(_0, _1)              PP_JOIN_HELPER_HELPER(_0, _1)
#define PP_JOIN_IMPL(_0, _1)                PP_JOIN_HELPER(_0, _1)

#define PP_JOIN_2(_0, _1)                                                                   PP_JOIN_IMPL(_0, _1)
#define PP_JOIN_3(_0, _1, _2)                                                               PP_JOIN_2(PP_JOIN_2(_0, _1), _2)
#define PP_JOIN_4(_0, _1, _2, _3)                                                           PP_JOIN_2(PP_JOIN_3(_0, _1, _2), _3)
#define PP_JOIN_5(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4)                                                       PP_JOIN_2(PP_JOIN_4(_0, _1, _2, _3), _4)
#define PP_JOIN_6(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5)                                                   PP_JOIN_2(PP_JOIN_5(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4), _5)
#define PP_JOIN_7(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6)                                               PP_JOIN_2(PP_JOIN_6(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5), _6)
#define PP_JOIN_8(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7)                                           PP_JOIN_2(PP_JOIN_7(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6), _7)
#define PP_JOIN_9(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8)                                       PP_JOIN_2(PP_JOIN_8(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7), _8)
#define PP_JOIN_10(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9)                                  PP_JOIN_2(PP_JOIN_9(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8), _9)
#define PP_JOIN_11(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10)                             PP_JOIN_2(PP_JOIN_10(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9), _10)
#define PP_JOIN_12(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11)                        PP_JOIN_2(PP_JOIN_11(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10), _11)
#define PP_JOIN_13(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12)                   PP_JOIN_2(PP_JOIN_12(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11), _12)
#define PP_JOIN_14(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13)              PP_JOIN_2(PP_JOIN_13(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12), _13)
#define PP_JOIN_15(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13, _14)         PP_JOIN_2(PP_JOIN_14(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13), _14)
#define PP_JOIN_16(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13, _14, _15)    PP_JOIN_2(PP_JOIN_15(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13, _14), _15)

// Chooses a value based on a condition.
#define PP_IF_0(t, f)           f
#define PP_IF_1(t, f)           t
#define PP_IF(cond, t, f)       PP_JOIN_2(PP_IF_, PP_TO_BOOL(cond))(t, f)

// Converts a condition into a boolean 0 (=false) or 1 (=true).
#define PP_TO_BOOL_0 0
#define PP_TO_BOOL_1 1
#define PP_TO_BOOL_2 1
#define PP_TO_BOOL_3 1
#define PP_TO_BOOL_4 1
#define PP_TO_BOOL_5 1
#define PP_TO_BOOL_6 1
#define PP_TO_BOOL_7 1
#define PP_TO_BOOL_8 1
#define PP_TO_BOOL_9 1
#define PP_TO_BOOL_10 1
#define PP_TO_BOOL_11 1
#define PP_TO_BOOL_12 1
#define PP_TO_BOOL_13 1
#define PP_TO_BOOL_14 1
#define PP_TO_BOOL_15 1
#define PP_TO_BOOL_16 1

#define PP_TO_BOOL(x)       PP_JOIN_2(PP_TO_BOOL_, x)

// Returns 1 if the arguments to the variadic macro are separated by a comma, 0 otherwise.
#define PP_HAS_COMMA(...)                           PP_HAS_COMMA_EVAL(PP_HAS_COMMA_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0))
#define PP_HAS_COMMA_EVAL(...)                      __VA_ARGS__
#define PP_HAS_COMMA_ARGS(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13, _14, _15, _16, ...) _16

// Returns 1 if the argument list to the variadic macro is empty, 0 otherwise.
#define PP_IS_EMPTY(...)                                                        \
    PP_HAS_COMMA                                                                \
    (                                                                           \
        PP_JOIN_5                                                           \
        (                                                                       \
            PP_IS_EMPTY_CASE_,                                              \
            PP_HAS_COMMA(__VA_ARGS__),                                      \
            PP_HAS_COMMA(PP_IS_EMPTY_BRACKET_TEST __VA_ARGS__),         \
            PP_HAS_COMMA(__VA_ARGS__ (~)),                                  \
            PP_HAS_COMMA(PP_IS_EMPTY_BRACKET_TEST __VA_ARGS__ (~))      \
        )                                                                       \
    )

#define PP_IS_EMPTY_CASE_0001           ,
#define PP_IS_EMPTY_BRACKET_TEST(...)   ,

// Retrieve the number of arguments handed to a variable-argument macro.
#define PP_VA_NUM_ARGS_HELPER(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13, _14, _15, _16, N, ...)    N
#define PP_VA_NUM_ARGS(...) PP_VA_NUM_ARGS_HELPER(__VA_ARGS__, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)

// Correctly handles the case of 0 arguments.
#define PP_NUM_ARGS(...)        PP_IF(PP_IS_EMPTY(__VA_ARGS__), 0, PP_VA_NUM_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__))

// Pass each variable in a VA_ARGS list to a macro.
#define PP_FE_0(action, X)
#define PP_FE_1(action, X) action(X)
#define PP_FE_2(action, X, ...) action(X)PP_FE_1(action, __VA_ARGS__)
#define PP_FE_3(action, X, ...) action(X)PP_FE_2(action, __VA_ARGS__)
#define PP_FE_4(action, X, ...) action(X)PP_FE_3(action, __VA_ARGS__)
#define PP_FE_5(action, X, ...) action(X)PP_FE_4(action, __VA_ARGS__)
#define PP_FE_6(action, X, ...) action(X)PP_FE_5(action, __VA_ARGS__)
#define PP_FE_7(action, X, ...) action(X)PP_FE_6(action, __VA_ARGS__)
#define PP_FE_8(action, X, ...) action(X)PP_FE_7(action, __VA_ARGS__)
#define PP_FE_9(action, X, ...) action(X)PP_FE_8(action, __VA_ARGS__)
#define PP_FE_10(action, X, ...) action(X)PP_FE_9(action, __VA_ARGS__)
#define PP_FE_11(action, X, ...) action(X)PP_FE_10(action, __VA_ARGS__)
#define PP_FE_12(action, X, ...) action(X)PP_FE_11(action, __VA_ARGS__)
#define PP_FE_13(action, X, ...) action(X)PP_FE_12(action, __VA_ARGS__)
#define PP_FE_14(action, X, ...) action(X)PP_FE_13(action, __VA_ARGS__)
#define PP_FE_15(action, X, ...) action(X)PP_FE_14(action, __VA_ARGS__)
#define PP_FE_16(action, X, ...) action(X)PP_FE_15(action, __VA_ARGS__)

#define PP_FOR_EACH(action, ...) PP_JOIN_2(PP_FE_, PP_NUM_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__))(action, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Definition for your macro:

```
#define CREATE_VAR(var)     double var{smc::define_variable(data, var, #var)};
#define CREATE_VARS(...)    PP_FOR_EACH(CREATE_VAR, __VA_ARGS__)
```

---

Also, you may or may not need to use `#pragma GCC system_header` depending on what warning lvl you're compiling with in order to get rid of `ISO C99 requires rest arguments to be used`. You could've used `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-pedantic-errors"` but apparently [that is bugged](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48914). If you're using msvc you'll have to figure out the warning to disable by yourself.

Comment: Nice Code. Did you make this yourself? I don;t know yet if my code will be boost independent atm but if it will this will definitely come in handy. Sorry I can't accept this answer, at the moment @angew came first and is short and sweet - currently works for me. Thanks for the alternative for myself and everyone else to see. Appreciate it.

Comment: @woosah Its mostly a cleaned up version of a piece of code I found on [altdevblogaday](http://www.altdevblogaday.com/). I personally prefer going boost free. You could simply create a file `pp.h` and include it in the files where you need such `FOR_EACH` and `JOIN` macro helpers. Its always better to not depend on external libraries when possible.

Answer (score 0):

These are called Variadic Macros, A macro can be declared to accept a variable number of arguments much as a function can.

The declaration syntax is similar to that of variadic functions: an ellipsis "..." is used to indicate that one or more arguments must be passed. Common compilers also permit passing zero arguments to such a macro, however. During macro expansion each occurrence of the special identifier **VA_ARGS** in the macro replacement list is replaced by the passed arguments.

For example C99 way, also supported by VC++ compiler.

```
#define FOO(fmt, ...) print(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)

void print(const char *fmt, ...) {

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vsprintf(str, fmt, args);
        va_end(args);

        printf("%s\n", str);

}
```

This is a simple use case to show how to use vardiac maco and then how we can use the variable argument list correctly...with out looking for additional library!

Also have a look at

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html

Comment: IMO, that's just a partial answer. How would one use `__VA_ARGS__` to process each argument separately?

Comment: There are different ways to use it, have a look at http://tdistler.com/2010/06/21/macros-with-variable-argument-lists, my mistake i missed it

Comment: Well, this still just takes all the variadic arguments and passes them as a sequence someplace else (to a variadic C function). How would you use a variadic macro to create one C++ declaration for each argument passed?

Comment: Did you got chance to look at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html? You got a variadic macro, but now it depends one someone how to use , for example i can use a vardiac C function which use this argument list... printf was just an example to show how some one can benefit...

Comment: Yes, I did. The OP wants to use the macro to define one `double` variable for each argument of the macro. How do you do that with variadics? Note that the question wasn't "how to write a variadic macro?", but "how to have just one macro to solve my particular problem?"

Comment: "Is there a way to simplify this by using one macro _CREATE_VAR instead of having multiple instances with different variable argumentsand corresponding names? Ideally, I would like to automatically call the same macro _CREATE_VAR regardless of how many arguments."

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of your question. you should use ellipsis(...).  I suggest you to go through with following link. This is help full to understand.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177415(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: IMO, that's just a partial answer. How would one use `__VA_ARGS__` to process each argument separately?